# How do I expand this function around zero?

Tags: taylor-expansion

The function is

$$ \sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}} $$
I need to expand it to the order $x^2$ around $0$. The solution is supposed to be:

$$ 1-\frac{x^2}{12}+\mathcal{O}(x^4) $$

How do I proceed?

Comment: Just use the definition of a Taylor series.

Comment: Somewhat faster than Taylor series, you know the series for $\sin x$ (or work it out from $e^{ix}$), so you want $(1-x^2/6+O(x^4))^{1/2}$ and you know that series too, giving $1-x^2/12+O(x^4)$.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going through the square of a series, i.e.
$$
f(x) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {a_{\,j} \,x^{\,j} }  = \sqrt {{{\sin x} \over x}}  = \left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} {{x^{\,2\,k} } \over {\left( {2k + 1} \right)!}}} } \right)^{\,1/2} 
$$
so that
$$
f(x)^{\,2}  \approx \left( {a_{\,0} \, + a_{\,1} x^{\,1}  + a_{\,2} x^{\,2}  + O(x^{\,3} )} \right)^{\,2}  \approx \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} {{x^{\,2\,k} } \over {\left( {2k + 1} \right)!}}} 
$$
and therefrom:
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  a_{\,0} ^{\,2}  = 1\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a_{\,0}  = f(0) = 1 \hfill \cr 
  2\,a_{\,0} \,a_{\,1}  = 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a_{\,1}  = 0 \hfill \cr 
  a_{\,1} ^{\,2}  + 2\,a_{\,0} \,a_{\,2}  = 2\,a_{\,2}  =  - {1 \over {3!}}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a_{\,2}  =  - {1 \over {12}} \hfill \cr 
  2\,a_{\,0} \,a_{\,3}  + 2\,a_{\,1} \,a_{\,2}  = 2\,a_{\,3}  = 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a_{\,3}  = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$